# Equation solver webapp in Python

Tags: python, ajax, matplotlib

I am making an equation solver webapp in Python (Flask framework).  App takes user input [a, b, c] and sent to server by calling a server side python function and get the results displayed using AJAX.

Part of Client JavaScript:

```
$.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_serverFunction', { form data });
```

Server Python function:

```
@app.route('/_solve')
def solve():
    a = request.args.get('a')
    b = request.args.get('b')
    c = request.args.get('c')
    cof = [a, b, c]
    roots = np.roots(cof)
    return jsonify(roots)
```

Above works just fine and i get the results displayed as per the input.

However, I would also like to show a graph representing the solution next to the above results.

I am able to generate a dummy static graph at server using matplotlib and send to the client with the following:

```
<img src="/image.jpg" id='bg'>
```

Server side python code:

```
 @app.route('/image.jpg')
    def image_jpeg():
        image = StringIO()
        plot(image)
        image.seek(0)
        return send_file(image,
                         attachment_filename="image.jpg",
                         as_attachment=True)

def plot(image):
    x = np.linspace(0, 100)
    y = np.sin(x)
    pyplot.plot(x, y)
    pyplot.savefig(image, format='jpg')
```

Above works and I get a static curve when i load the page. But I would like this graph to change when user submits the input to the server to solve the equation every time.

How to make the both calls to the solve() and image_jpeg() from the same same AJAX call?

How do the I share the user data [a , b ,c] across functions so the graph can be generated and sent back.

***Update:***

```
$('img').attr('src',"data:image/png;base64"+ "," + data.imgdata);
```

On server:

```
    imgdata = image.getvalue()    
import base64
imgdata = base64.b64encode(imgdata)
```

imgData is passed along with json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One request can't become two, unfortunately, but there is a way of doing what you want.

In order to achieve this, you could send the image as a [data url](https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/) inside the JSON you request from your server, then in JS you simply set the image element's **src** attribute the data.

You would start by moving the **image_jpeg** function into your solve method, since you have the image data in a string already all you need to do is encode it into base64 and prefix it with **"data:image/png;base64,"** changing the mime to suit the image format.

Also, to complete the answer, you can share user data across functions. You would usually use Cookies, in Flask they wrap cookies in Sessions to make it even easier for you, [take a look](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#sessions). That being said, I don't think they fit this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to change the client to just explicitly load the image, passing the same arguments that it passed to the `solve` API.

Another option is to pass the image contents back from `solve` as another value. Your client code can then build an `img` with a `data:` in its `src`.

Finally, you can use a [session](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/category/sessions/) to store information between calls from the same client, so every time someone calls `solve` you stash their arguments as "last_solve_args", and then you can use them inside `image`. (The client will, of course, still have to reload the image, so this is really no better than the first one.)

Comment: I will implement the session functionality once solver algorithm is fixed with proper dynamic image, which i am still trying to figure out.